# How to import BigQuery codes to the GitHub

Tags: sql, github, google-bigquery

I am trying to import the SQL code from BigQueries to GitHub. But I cannot able to do that, can somebody please let me know how can we import the BigQueries to the GitHub.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 3rd party IDE for BigQuery supporting GitHub
This is Goliath - part of [Potens.io](https://potensio.zendesk.com/) Suite available at [Marketplace](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/potens-io/potensio).

[image]

***Note**: Another tool in this suite is Magnus - Workflow Automator. Supports all BigQuery, Cloud Storage and most of Google APIs as well as multiple simple utility type Tasks like BigQuery Task, Export to Storage Task, Loop Task and many many more along with advanced scheduling, triggering, etc. Supports GitHub as a source control as well*

***Disclosure**: I am GDE for Google Cloud and creator of those tools and leader on Potens team*

Comment: Thank you so much, Mikhail Berlyant. It seems like Potens.io has the free trial of 15 days. If I need to add BigQueries to GitHub after these 15 days, how can I proceed further...

Comment: when free trial period ends  - you still can use Goliath forever (with some limited but still extensive feature set). As of Magnus - your organization will need to by licenses - in this case you get whole Potens available for you! you can see more details on [Potens knowledge site](https://potensio.zendesk.com)

Comment: sure. contact me on LinkedIn if any questions